# Text Documents Outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook, text-files

I was wondering if there is any way to read informations out from a text file with VBA in Outlook 2007.

Thanks for attention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  Private Sub Command1_Click()
    'Declare variables.
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    'Open file.
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Environ("windir") & "\system.ini")
    'Loop while not at the end of the file.
    Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
      Debug.Print ts.ReadLine
    Loop
    'Close the file.
    ts.Close
  End Sub
```

From [MSDN FSO Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186118/en-us)

Way more comfortable then `Open sPath, #FileNo`. You need to add FSO to your project with "Tools -> References", like it's described in the MSDN.